# check text if is empty

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html dir = rtl>
    <head>
        <title> </title>
        <meta HTTP-EQUIV="Content-language" CONTENT="ar">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function CheckForm(String)
            {
                 var pNames = [ "sName", "sAge", "sAddress"];
                 for (var i = 0; i < 4;i++)
                 {
             if (Infi[i].value == "")
                         document.getElementById(pNames[i]).innerHTML = 'عفواً لاتوجد قيمة في الحقل';
                 }
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <form name = "Info" method = "set" action = "#">
           <table  border = "0" width = "80%" align = "center">
               <tr>
                   <td align = "left"> الاســــــــــــــــم: </td>
                   <td > <input type="text" name = "CurName" size = "31"> <p id = "sName" style = "display: inline"> </p> </td>
               </tr>

               <tr>
                   <td align = "left"> العــــــــــــــــمر :</td>
                   <td> <input type = "text" name = "CurAge" size = "10"> <p id = "sAge" style = "display: inline"> </p> </td>
               </tr>

               <tr>
                   <td  align = "left"> العنـــــــــــــوان :</td>
                   <td> <input type = "text" name = "CurAddress" size = "45"> <p id = "sAddress" style = "display: inline"> </p> </td>
               </tr>

               <tr>
                   <td  align = "left"> الحالــــــــــــــــة :</td>
                   <td> <input type = "radio" name = "Mar" > متزوج<input type = "radio" name = "Sin" checked="yes"> أعزب </td>
               </tr>

               <tr>                   
                  <td colspan = 2 align = center> <button type = "button" onclick = "CheckForm(); return false;">ارسال </button>  <button type = "reset">مسح</button> </td>                 
               </tr>
          </table>
       </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to check the form boxes if they are empty or not and i'm try a lot but nothing works well so please any one can help me , sorry for my bad english

Comment: waht is the issue with current code.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your form name is `Info`, not `Infi`. It appears you have a typo.

This:

```
if (Infi[i].value == "")
```

Should be this:

```
if (Info[i].value == "")
```

Comment: hahahaha really i'm stupid guy anyway thank you a lot

Comment: Come on guys, a -1 for the first correct answer?

Comment: there is a problem i gave you +1 really don't know what happend

Comment: You last voted on this answer
8 mins ago
Your vote is now locked in
unless this answer is edited

Answer (score 2):

You have to correct the typo in the code:

The name of your form must be `Info` instead of `Infi`.

Answer (score 1):

Infi is not defined error.You didn't define the infi..